# CakePHP ACL: How to implement this case?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-acl

Because I have been trying to find a good way to make this for about two weeks, I thought it'd be a good idea to just ask.

I have two `User` roles: `editor` and `admin`. Every `editor` has a range of `Region`s assigned to him, via `$hasAndBelongsToMany`.

In the app I also have a model `Event`, each of which has a `Region`, via a `region_id`. I want to make sure that every `editor` may view, edit, delete and do other things only those `Event`s that are in a `Region` of his assignment. A `admin` user may of course edit anything.

How can I implement this with the least fuss in my CakePHP models and controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in first few lines of the `edit` method of your `EventsController`. Find the region of the event and then check if the logged in editor is editor of that region. All you'd need to do is make sure that when a user logs in, his/her role is saved in the `AuthComponent`'s session. For example:

```
public function edit($event_id = null) {
    if($this->Auth->user('role') == "editor") {
        // User is logged in as editor, check if the Event region matches his regions.
        $event = $this->Event->findById($event_id); // Get the event
        $user = $this->Event->User->findById($this->Auth->user('id')); // Get the user (Assuming an Event belongsTo user, otherwise you'll have to load the model first).

        if(!array_search($event['Event']['region_id'], $user['User']['Region'])) {
            // The event's region wasn't found in the Regions for the User, deny access
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to edit this event.'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $event_id));
        }
    }
}
```

So basically before you do any other logic, you check if the user is an editor and if so, if the regions he's associated to matches the region for the current event. If it doesn't a flash message is set and the user is kicked back to the `view` view for the event.

Comment: So no ACL necessary at all? What about `isAuthorized`?

Comment: ACL is just to determine if an authenticated user is authorized to access a specific action in your controller. In this case both editors and admins have access, you just need an additional check if they are allowed to edit that specific event. ACL won't check that kind of model relation.